# How to create htaccess seo friendly url rewriterules for e.g a/b/c

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm searching from last few days and here in **stackoverflow**, there are lots of questions but unfortunately, none is working for me, that's why I'm asking according to my problem

I have to create a beautiful SEO friendly urls using htaccess. Some of the tasks have been completed but one link still needs to be SEO friendly. e.g example.com/pages/my-page/my-page-first-post

details:
`example.com` is my site 
`pages` is rewritten rules `page.php` 
`my-page` is SEO friendly title of the page

Now what I need is 
`my-page-first-post` so the url must be `example.com/pages/my-page/my-page-first-post`
 It is fine till `example.com/page/my-page/`

working htaccess code `RewriteRule ^pages/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1 [QSA,L]` and I'm trying for adding pages posts titles. `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1/page.php?title=$2 [QSA,L]`

Thanks for helping in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These 2 rules should be able to handle your pretty URL schemes:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1&title=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine, but the confusion is that, Do i have to rerun the `$_GET...` query on the same page `pages.php` or have to create another page? `I mean I already running a page query on page.php`

Comment: You don't need another page. Inside `page.php` just use `$_GET['pages']` and `$_GET['title']` to fetch both query parameters. Just remember that `$_GET['title']` will be there only if URL in browser is like `example.com/pages/my-page/my-page-first-post`

Comment: you really made simple my problem, but just one step is remaining. I just know a single get query e.g, `if(isset($_GET['page'])){...` or do i have to use `if(isset($_GET['page'] and $_GET['title'])){....` Thanks for being hepking.

Comment: can you please help me to add another query?  `example.com/pages/my-page/my-page-first-question/` I have added a post to my link but I've another table for questions now I want also to add question section. so we have added `page.php?pages=$1&title=$2` I want to replace `title` with `question` if some click on the question link. I hope you understand what I mean?

Comment: kindly I have posted a question I'm sure you can solve this, thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551471/how-to-change-already-working-get-query-with-the-change-of-requested-get-data-us