# How to change already working GET query with the change of requested GET data using htaccess in php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm sure by posting here in **stackoverflow** with the requirements I can get the solutions.

I'm working on a web application where I have pages and inside on each page, there are posts features and questions. For which I have two tables in SQL `posts` and `questions`. Now What I want is:

1: When a user clicks on the post link (inside in page), the user has to redirect to a single post page with SEO friendly URLs which is working.

`RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`
`RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1&title=$2 [QSA,NC,L]`

`pages` is for `GET` page query 
`titles` is for `GET` post query 
`question` now i need for `GET` Question query on the same page which I used for post `GET` query.

2: When a user clicks on the question link (inside in page), the user has to redirect to a single question page.

Working `example.com/pages/my-page/my-page-first-Post` 
Required `example.com/pages/my-page/my-page-first-Question`

This data comes from two different  `SQL tables`

Comment: `/pages/my-page/my-page-first-Post` and `/pages/my-page/my-page-first-Question` are following same structure that's why rewrite can happen to either `?pages=$1&title=$2` or `?pages=$1&question=$2` but not both at the same time. You can add a marker for question page e.g. `/pages/my-page/question/my-page-first-Question` to handle it differently.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I did the same you told `?pages=$1&question=$2` and also change the structure `href="pages/my-page/q/my-page-first-Question"` but it is not working, while i also created a new page for `page-questions.php` where I added `isset(GET['question']{....}` query as well. But page not found error occurs. I hope you understand what want to explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use 3 separate rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# /pages/my-page
RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# for URI /pages/my-page/my-page-first-Post
RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1&title=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

# for URI /pages/my-page/q/my-page-first-Question 
RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/q/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1&question=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Inside your `page.php` code you can check:

```
if (isset($_GET['question')) {
    // question page
    // work with $_GET['page') and $_GET['question')
} else if (isset($_GET['title')) {
    // post page
    // work with $_GET['page') and $_GET['title')
} else {
    // single page
    // work with $_GET['page')
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, working fine as i expecting. now I have to add a last section to my url e.g `example.com/pages/my-page/followers`, where i want to display total number of users who follows my page. I created something like this, `RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/followers/([\w-]+)/?$ page.php?pages=$1&followers=$2 [QSA,NC,L]`

Comment: I already added another question, thanks for being helping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642038/how-to-rewrite-seo-friendly-url-in-htaccess