# how to rewrite SEO friendly url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to create an SEO friendly URL like `example.com/pages/my-first-page/followers` here I want how to create a structure in `if(isset($_GET['followers'])){...}` and `htaccess file`.

My link working fine till `example.com/pages/my-first-page/` but now I want to add `followers` section.
I hope i explain well what I expecting. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Rule you've suggested is this:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([\w-]+)/followers/?$ page.php?pages=$1&followers=1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This is pretty good rule and there is no reason why it should not work. Make sure this rule is placed **before** page rule which is your first rule in .htaccess

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I have a bit of confusion, that how to structure my link and GET query, e.g, I used for a page `href="pages/<?php echo $page_slug;?>"` but what to use for followers `href="pages/<?php echo $page_slug;?>/followers/<? php (?) ?>"', I hope you understand what I mean?

Comment: this will show just one follower or a list of followers?.

Comment: I want to show another page according to page followers `pages/my-page/followers/['list-of-my-page-followers']`

Comment: Whatever string you have in URL after `/followers/` will be captured in `$_GET['followers']`

Comment: this is the reason, i don't have a string while I want to fetch all the users who follow the page.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand. What is the new URL you want to show in browser and how do you want it to rewrite internally?

Comment: I'm sending a demo link `https://www.quora.com/q/smg/people` where `q` is a spaces-page `smg` is a space and `people` are those who follow spaces. the same  thing i need. where I want to show a list of users who follows the current page.e.g if there are 50 users in a system, and 20 users following a page named `my-page` so I want to display only these 20 users here `example.com/pages/my-page/followers`. I hope I explain it well now. Thanks for your valued answer.

Comment: ok got need it. In that case you will need my updated rule. Here in your php code just check `if (!empty($_GET['followers']) { // follower page }` and on your page use this to display link: `href="pages/<?php echo $page_slug;?>/followers`

Comment: `<?php if(!isset($_GET['question']) && !isset($_GET['post']) && !isset($_GET['followers'])){?><br>
            <?php include 'include/main-page.php';?>
            <?php }?><br>
            <?php if(isset($_GET['post'])){?>
            <?php include 'include/post.php';?>
            <?php }?><br>
            <?php if(isset($_GET['followers'])){?>
            <?php include 'include/followers.php';?>
            <?php }?>
            <?php if(isset($_GET['question'])){?>
            <br>
            <?php include 'include/question.php';?>
            <?php }?>`

Comment: when I'm placing a string of a page `id` then it works fine `pages/my-page/followers/<php echo $page_id;?>` You may clear it well in your last comment but I think i didn't understand that clear.

Comment: I cannot understand php code from comment so please add it in your question. Also `pages/my-page/followers/<php echo $page_id;?>` is unclear. Should it not be as I wrote in previous comment

Comment: when i am using this kind of link `href="pages/my-page/followers/<php echo $page_id;?>"`, and also use `$_GET['followers']`, then I can fetch all the users. but I dont want to show `page_id` etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220819/discussion-between-anubhava-and-sami-ullah).